# передача в текущий url новых переменных из js c помощью ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, .htaccess, url

текущий url : http://jew/catalog/rings

.htaccess

```
AddType "text/html; charset=utf-8" .htm .html
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
PHP_VALUE default_charset utf-8

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^card/?$                           card.php
RewriteRule ^catalog/?$                        catalog.php
RewriteRule ^catalog/([a-z_-]+)/?$      catalog.php?name_en=$1
RewriteRule ^catalog/([a-z_-]+)/([0-9]+)$       catalog.php?     name_en=$1&limit=$2
RewriteRule ^stock/([a-z_-]+)/?$               catalog.php?stock=$1
RewriteRule ^product/([0-9]+)$                 product.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^collections/([a-z_-]+)/?$         collections.php?type=$1
```

jew.js

```
var size = new Array();
var material = new Array();
var vstavki = new Array();
var filter= new Array();
var price =new Array();
$(document).on('click', '.btn', function(){
    var price_min = $('.min').find('.val').text();
    var price_max = $('.max').find('.val').text();
    price = [];
    size = [];
    material = [];
    vstavki = [];
    filter= [];
    var min = $('.min').find('.val').text();
    var max = $('.max').find('.val').text();
    price.push(min,max);
    filter.push(price);
    $("input:checkbox[name='size']:checked").each(function(){
            size.push($(this).val());
    });
    filter.push(size);
    $("input:checkbox[name='material']:checked").each(function(){
        material.push($(this).val());
    });
    filter.push(material);
    $("input:checkbox[name='vstavki']:checked").each(function(){
        vstavki.push($(this).val());
    });
    filter.push(vstavki);
    var  search = JSON.stringify(filter);
    console.log(filter);
    console.log(search);
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "GET", 
        url: "",
        dataType: "json", 
        data: "search="+search,
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

script.php:

```
var_dump("$_GET");
```

Т.е есть урл с кучей переменных по которым была выведена данная страница, на этой странице я жму кнопку и в js формируется массив , который нужно передать на текущую страницу с текущими значениями в урле , т.е. нужно как-то добавить новую переменную с массивом в конец текущего урла и соответственно перезагрузить текущую страницу с уже новым дополненным урлом дабы вывести новые данные.

Comment: вообще непонятно, что у вас есть сейчас, что вы хотите сделать и на каком этапе находитесь(что уже сделали)?

Comment: покажите код который у вас уже есть

Comment: так все-таки приведите пример url который вы хотите получить? и не совсем понятно зачем вы тогда делаете _ajax_?

Comment: http://jew/catalog/rings/search/

Comment: в таком случае, если у вас сейчас url _http://jew/catalog/rings_ вам достаточно изменить свойство _location_: `location.href += "/search"`

Comment: и что? таким образом я передам в url значение массива search ?

Comment: нет конечно, вы же не написали как это значение массива должно выглядеть в url, как вы с ним хотите потом работать

Comment: я хочу в catalog.php через $_GET['search'] получить  массив переданный из js

Comment: ну вот например  есть url : jew.ru/name_en=rings
нужно url : jew.ru/name_en=rings&search=массив

Comment: просто меня еще и  .htaccess с толку сбивает , в котором я вообще 0.

Comment: c `.htaccess` вряд ли помогу, по поводу параметра, ничего не мешает также отправлять его как и сейчас: `search=JSON.stringify(filter);`, чтобы сам url выглядел: [1,2,3], и на сервере уже из этого json получать масив с помощью  [json-decode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: в том то и дело, что если напишу:
location.href += "/search="+search; 
то получаю  http://jew/catalog/rings/search=[["10%20000","150%20000"],[],[],[]]
и Error 404

Comment: это тоже добавляйте в вопрос, и конечный url который в итоге запрашиваете

Comment: суть в том что полученный url не подходит под ваши _RewriteRule_, но чтобы знать какое правило добавить - нужно знать с каким запросом мы прихоим

Comment: в общем, чтоб не парится прописал в htaccess любые символы, вот это--> ([^/]*), целиком такой-->

                   ^catalog/([a-zA-Z0-9.&-]+)/([^/]*)$
и в итоге получил свой массив :)

Comment: вполне себе вариант :-) можете добавить его как ответ на ваш вопрос

Comment: А подскажите как сделать  чтобы location.href += "&search="+search; перезаписывал search  в url ? о то при каждом новом клике он мне постоянно добавляет новый &search=массив и получается куча  повторяющихся &search=массив  в url-е

Comment: можете вместо этого использовать свойство _search_ у _location_: `location.search = "search="+search`

Comment: не подходит такой вариант, т.к. перед search в урле уже есть параметры, а ваша конструкция добавляет знак "?" перед search , a нужен знак "&"

Comment: я думаю лучше поправить регулярку в .htacces :-)

Comment: например:  `^catalog/([a-z_-]+)/.+\?search=(.+)$       catalog.php?     name_en=$1&search=$2`